# remove space between links with css

Tags: html, css

I have this webapp for ios and in a certain page i have an div with 3 buttons.

this div is centered and it has `460px` inside this div i have 3 links, the first and the last with `153px` and the middle one `154px`

the problem is:
if i add this 3 links together with no space between it will be ok. but if i add a newline between them it wont apear ok.

like this:
http://jsfiddle.net/NicosKaralis/zJxfs/1/

i want the second set off link to be just like the first set of links...

is there any css property that allows me that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`display:inline-block` adds about `4px` to the left of each element by default. To overcome this, just define a negative margin to the left of each element (`margin-left:-4px;`), or just float your elements to the left.

Comment: thanks... it worked... just wait the minimum time and i`ll accept... thanks again

Comment: -1. This is incorrect. Margin is not added by the inline-block, and -4px is rarely a good idea. The space added is because there is space character between the <a>. If they are put on the same line with no space between them, no space character is added.

Comment: in Twig use minus `{{--}}` and|or `{%-spaceless-%}`